# Execute SqlPS Scripts from Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, powershell

I would like to execute sqlps scripts from asp.net. With this [article](http://www.leastprivilege.com/HostingPowerShellInASPNET.aspx)  I was able to run simple powershell comannds but don't know how to invoke sqlps.

Thanks,
Fahad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok figure it out. Had to add sql server snapins to Runspace and it worked

```
 RSpace.RunspaceConfiguration.AddPSSnapIn("SqlServerCmdletSnapin100", out obj);
 RSpace.RunspaceConfiguration.AddPSSnapIn("SqlServerProviderSnapin100", out obj);
```